# What is the minimum value of $x$ for which this "reciprocal pronic" series, $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^x(n+1)^x}$, converges?

Tags: sequences-and-series

If we define a function as:
$$P(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^x(n+1)^x}$$
For $x=1$, we have a standard telescoping series that sums to $1$.  For $x=2$, the series sums to $\frac{\pi^2}{3}-3$.  For $x=3$, the series sums to $10-\pi^2$, ... and so on.

> My question is, what is the minimum value for which x allows this "Reciprocal Pronic" series to converge.  I think it is something above $x>0.5$ but I cannot prove this.

Comment: Think integral test. Your numerator is a constant,  so your denominator should be of degree more than 1. (Why?)

Comment: I am aware that convergence is possible for values 0.5<x<1.

Comment: Note the binomial series $(1+n^{-1})^{-s}=\sum_{k\ge 0} {-s \choose k} n^{-k}$ means $$\sum_{n\ge 1} n^{-s}(n+1)^{-s} = \sum_{n\ge 1} n^{-2s}\sum_{k\ge 0} {-s \choose k} n^{-k}=\sum_{k\ge 0} {-s \choose k} \sum_{n\ge 1}n^{-2s-k}=\sum_{k\ge 0} {-s \choose k} \zeta(2s+k)$$ which gives the analytic continuation to the whole complex plane, with simple poles at $s=(1-2m)/2,m\ge 0$.

Comment: Very clever - thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint** Use inequalities to write bounds for the summand that involve simpler expressions: $$\frac{1}{(n + 1)^{2x}} \leq \frac{1}{n^x (n + 1)^x} \leq \frac{1}{n^{2x}}.$$

It follows from doing so that there is no minimal $x$ for which the series converges, but one can instead for the infimum of the set of $x$ for which it does.

Comment: That is helpful but not conclusive.  This only places an upper limit which I suspect is the correct limit but I want to go further.

Comment: Actually it places both an upper and lower limit

Comment: @user714524 The inequalities bound the summand both above and below---essentially by $p$-series, which suggests using the $p$-series Test and the Comparison Test.